# Why is apple sign-in with FirebaseUI not working?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Following the guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui) I am attempting to add Apple sign-in to my iOS app. I have successfully implemented google sign-in with this method but Apple does not seem to be working. I can get to the point where it asks for my apple password but then it just keeps loading without result and I get the following errors:

```
2020-12-10 13:19:38.020129-0500 Pikit[5268:114225] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2020-12-10 13:19:38.121991-0500 Pikit[5268:114225] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
```

To be clear these errors appear after I have selected to share my email with the app and before actually entering a password. If I type an incorrect password then it informs me, but if I type the correct password it does not proceed. It does not hang, it simply will not continue with no explanation.

Here is the code that triggers the login flow:

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        guard authUI != nil else {
           return
        }
        authUI?.providers = [
            FUIEmailAuth(),
            FUIGoogleAuth(),
            FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider()
        ]
        authUI?.delegate = self
        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
        authViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
//This function is not being triggered
    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        if let user = authDataResult?.user{
            print("Nice! You've signed in as \(user.uid)")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: K.welcomeSegue, sender: self)
        }
        print(error!)
    }
```

I have also made sure my Firebase project has enabled Apple, that apple sign-in is in my entitlements, and that I have uploaded my iOS auth key. I am running this on a simulator, does it need to be run from a real device?

**Update**

The `authUI` function is not running at all as I have tried inserting a print statement outside of the conditional and received no output. Why would this not be running?

The error appears to be occurring after I call the `present()` method.

**Update 2**

Full console output:

```
2020-12-11 13:53:55.697034-0500 Pikit[4563:85919] Task <9849E252-C9AF-4F35-88A7-1946BD0B4270>.<2> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000006edec0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <9849E252-C9AF-4F35-88A7-1946BD0B4270>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <9849E252-C9AF-4F35-88A7-1946BD0B4270>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasedynamiclinks-ipv6.googleapis.com/v1/installAttribution?key=AIzaSyDAKtfpyKw0QG5Db9jtdHYQfAOgI-FASWE, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://firebasedynamiclinks-ipv6.googleapis.com/v1/installAttribution?key=AIzaSyDAKtfpyKw0QG5Db9jtdHYQfAOgI-FASWE, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}
2020-12-11 13:53:55.733365-0500 Pikit[4563:85634] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>
2020-12-11 13:53:55.733582-0500 Pikit[4563:85634] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1098fed80 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 4565, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}
2020-12-11 13:53:55.977723-0500 Pikit[4563:85800] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: remote notifications are not supported in the simulator
2020-12-11 13:53:56.045387-0500 Pikit[4563:85800] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-12-11 13:53:56.227368-0500 Pikit[4563:85800] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-12-11 13:53:56.282593-0500 Pikit[4563:85800] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-12-11 13:53:56.355765-0500 Pikit[4563:85824] 6.25.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    dismiss = 1;
    "is_weak_match" = 1;
}
2020-12-11 13:54:25.474653-0500 Pikit[4563:85634] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2020-12-11 13:54:25.749707-0500 Pikit[4563:85634] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service
```

I have tried multiple different methods and read through the documentation many times but still cannot see what I am doing wrong.

**Update 3**

I have tried replacing each of the certificates/ keys and regenerating new ones with no effect

This is where I have been getting stopped in the sign-in flow:
[image: Here is the part of sign-in that my app gets stuck on]

**Update 4**

It appears that the error noted above does not occur after signing in, but is unrelated. When logging in I do not get any error. I do not understand why the `authUI()` function is not being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

House I have used the Apple Signin in an app but it is in Objective-c. The flow is very simple to test even in Objective-C if you are not used.

In the view with the login I added this sentence for delegate.

```
@import Firebase;
@import GoogleSignIn;

@interface loginViewController () <GIDSignInDelegate, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate>
```

Then after a button tap I execute the AppleSignIn ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate flow like this:

```
- (IBAction)startSignInWithAppleFlow:(id)sender
{
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        NSString *nonce = [self randomNonce:32];
        self.currentNonce = nonce;
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider *appleIDProvider = [[ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider alloc] init];
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest *request = [appleIDProvider createRequest];
        request.requestedScopes = @[ASAuthorizationScopeFullName, ASAuthorizationScopeEmail];
        request.nonce = [self stringBySha256HashingString:nonce];

        ASAuthorizationController *authorizationController = [[ASAuthorizationController alloc] initWithAuthorizationRequests:@[request]];
        authorizationController.delegate = self;
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self;
        [authorizationController performRequests];
    }
}

- (NSString *)stringBySha256HashingString:(NSString *)input
{
    const char *string = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(string, (CC_LONG)strlen(string), result);

    NSMutableString *hashed = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [hashed appendFormat:@"%02x", result[i]];
    }
    return hashed;
}

- (NSString *)randomNonce:(NSInteger)length
{
    NSAssert(length > 0, @"Expected nonce to have positive length");
    NSString *characterSet = @"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._";
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
    NSInteger remainingLength = length;

    while (remainingLength > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *randoms = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:16];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            uint8_t random = 0;
            int errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random);
            NSAssert(errorCode == errSecSuccess, @"Unable to generate nonce: OSStatus %i", errorCode);

            [randoms addObject:@(random)];
        }

        for (NSNumber *random in randoms) {
            if (remainingLength == 0) {
                break;
            }

            if (random.unsignedIntValue < characterSet.length) {
                unichar character = [characterSet characterAtIndex:random.unsignedIntValue];
                [result appendFormat:@"%C", character];
                remainingLength--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

- (void)authorizationController:(ASAuthorizationController *)controller didCompleteWithAuthorization:(ASAuthorization *)authorization API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))
{
    if ([authorization.credential isKindOfClass:[ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential class]]) {
        ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential *appleIDCredential = authorization.credential;
        NSString *rawNonce = self.currentNonce;
        NSAssert(rawNonce != nil, @"Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.");

        if (appleIDCredential.identityToken == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to fetch identity token.");
            return;
        }

        NSString *idToken = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:appleIDCredential.identityToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (idToken == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to serialize id token from data: %@", appleIDCredential.identityToken);
        }

        // Initialize a Firebase credential.
        FIROAuthCredential *credential = [FIROAuthProvider credentialWithProviderID:@"apple.com"
                                                                            IDToken:idToken
                                                                           rawNonce:rawNonce];

        // Sign in with Firebase.
        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential completion:^(FIRAuthDataResult * _Nullable authResult, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                // Error. If error.code == FIRAuthErrorCodeMissingOrInvalidNonce,
                // make sure you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string
                // with your request to Apple.
                
                NSLog(@"%ld - %@ - %@", error.code, error.description, error.localizedDescription);
                
                return;
            }
            // Sign-in succeeded!
            // User successfully signed in. Get user data from the FIRUser object
            if (authResult == nil) { return; }
            FIRUser *user = authResult.user;
            // ...
            NSLog(@"%@", user);
            
            // ...
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL" object:nil];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)authorizationController:(ASAuthorizationController *)controller didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))
{
    NSLog(@"Sign in with Apple errored: %@", error);
}
```

I don't know if you have follow the notes in this link: [Apple Sign In with FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple)
But if you follow them it should work in physical device, in simulator is not trivial make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I solved my issue but they removed my answer for some reason, so here you go.

Comment: Unfortunate. I could really use an answer to this. Of course I could use the answer above and setup apple login myself, but the whole point of FirebaseUI is to have a clean library that takes care of this for us.

do you happen to remember what you did to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add apple sign-in entitlements in your app bundle identifier from the apple developer account and from the apple developer account you have to download a key and upload that key to firebase and then your apple sign-in will start work, it is very common to create a key found on first searches of google very easily

Comment: and for me, it also works on a simulator but for best testing try it on a physical device

Comment: Hello Saqib and thank you for your answer. I have already added sign-in entitlements and downloaded the key to my firebase project.

Comment: did you allow attribute loads from info.plist ?

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

Comment: or may you have to call it in dispatch
DispatchQueue.main.async { }

Comment: I added that and still have the same result

Comment: To be clear, you meant to run the ```present()``` function in a dispatch queue?

Answer (score 0):

use this example i hope it will work for you

```
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        authUI?.shouldHideCancelButton = true
        authUI?.delegate = delegate
        authUI?.tosurl = Constants.Url.kFirebaseTermsOfService
        authUI?.privacyPolicyURL = Constants.Url.kFirebasePrivacyPolicy
        
        let emailAuth = FUIEmailAuth()
        let facebookAuth = FUIFacebookAuth(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"])
        let googleAuth = FUIGoogleAuth()
        
        var providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [emailAuth, facebookAuth, googleAuth]
        if useAnonymous {
            let anonymousAuth = FUIAnonymousAuth()
            providers.append(anonymousAuth)
        }

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let appleAuth = FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider()
            providers.append(appleAuth)
        }

        authUI?.providers = providers
```