# Apple sign in with FirebaseUI on iOS (Swift) not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebaseui, apple-sign-in

I can't sign in with an Apple account using FirebaseUI on iOS (Swift). I've successfully integrated email and Google sign in but Apple sign in doesn't work. I reach to the point where it asks for my Apple password but then it just keeps loading without result and I've no error on console output.

[image]

[image]

I followed the Firebase guides [Easily add sign-in to your iOS app with FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui#sign_in) and [Authenticate Using Apple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple) :

- Join the Apple Developer Program ✅
- Add Sign In with Apple capability ✅

[image]

- Enable Apple on Firebase Console as a sign-in provider ✅

[image]

- Add FirebaseUI packages on app

[image]

- Add Sign in with Apple method on app providers ✅

```
// Sign-in methods to support
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
    FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider(),
    FUIEmailAuth(),
    FUIGoogleAuth(authUI: authUI!)
]
authUI?.providers = providers
```

This existing stackoverflow question [Why is apple sign-in with FirebaseUI not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240217/why-is-apple-sign-in-with-firebaseui-not-working) is about this issue also but not exactly.

Any idea why Apple sign in not working with FirebaseUI on my project? Did I miss something?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Apple Sign-in thing only works when you run it with an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

I got a real device (an iPhone 8) and Apple sign in is well working now.

So the issue comes from using an iOS simulator. I find it unfortunate that this is not specified in the Firebase integration documentation or Apple sign in documentation (or maybe I haven't seen it).

Hope this experience can help other people.